# How to delete a heaped object in the Python wrapper generated with SWIG?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I am developing a Python module along with a C++ library. In the C++ code, I have a function which returns a heaped object as follows.

```
MyClass* func()
{
  MyClass* myclass = new MyClass();
  return myclass;
}
```

But when I use this function on the Python side, I cannot delete the returned object.

```
myclass = func()
del myclass # still remains in memory
```

Could anyone tell me how to delete the returned object in a Python code, please?

I can change the type of the return value from MyClass* to MyClass so that I can avoid this memory leak. But I do not want to touch the C++ code, because the C++ library is already in use in another place.

Comment: This is bad API design; you should probably have returned a shared pointer. Deprecate the function and change the callers. Not sure how this works with Python.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Um, not at all? Python's memory management is fully automatic, "shared pointer" or "raw pointer" doesn't even make sense.

Comment: @delnan Erm I was talking about the C++ API...

Comment: I do not think that this design is bad. You cannot use boost in all environments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the `%newobject` and `%typemap(newfree)` directives in section [11.2](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Customization_ownership) of SWIG's documentation.

Quoted from docs:

> A common problem in some applications is managing proper ownership of objects. For example, consider a function like this:

```
Foo *blah() {
   Foo *f = new Foo();
   return f;
}
```

> If you wrap the function blah(), SWIG has no idea that the return value is a newly allocated object. As a result, the resulting extension module may produce a memory leak (SWIG is conservative and will never delete objects unless it knows for certain that the returned object was newly created).
>
> To fix this, you can provide an extra hint to the code generator using the %newobject directive. For example:

```
%newobject blah;
Foo *blah();
```

> %newobject works exactly like %rename and %exception. In other words, you can attach it to class members and parameterized declarations as before. For example:

```
%newobject ::blah();                   // Only applies to global blah
%newobject Object::blah(int,double);   // Only blah(int,double) in Object
%newobject *::copy;                    // Copy method in all classes
...
```

> When %newobject is supplied, many language modules will arrange to take ownership of the return value. This allows the value to be automatically garbage-collected when it is no longer in use. However, this depends entirely on the target language (a language module may also choose to ignore the %newobject directive).
>
> Closely related to %newobject is a special typemap. The "newfree" typemap can be used to deallocate a newly allocated return value. It is only available on methods for which %newobject has been applied and is commonly used to clean-up string results. For example:

```
%typemap(newfree) char * "free($1);";
...
%newobject strdup;
...
char *strdup(const char *s);
```

> In this case, the result of the function is a string in the target language. Since this string is a copy of the original result, the data returned by strdup() is no longer needed. The "newfree" typemap in the example simply releases this memory.